# How can I implement mouse over on a <ul> in VueJS?

Tags: css, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Could any one help in implementing a mouse over function for UL, 
I have a set of UL tags in my template which uses the same class, but when I am trying to implement mouseover(changes border color on mouseover), all the UL tags with that class are getting highlighted.
I am pretty new to VUE.

Template

```
<ul v-bind:class="[sbitmcls]"  @mouseover="mouseOver" @mouseleave="mouseOut">
  <img src="../assets/notification.png" alt="" height="30" width="30">
  <span> Notification  </span>
</ul>

<ul v-bind:class="[sbitmcls]"  @mouseover="mouseOver" @mouseleave="mouseOut">
  <img src="../assets/message.png" alt="" height="30" width="30">
  <span> Message  </span>
</ul>
```

script

```
data() {
  return {
    sbitmcls: "image",
    active: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() {
    this.$router.push("/homepage");
  },
  mouseOver: function(name) {
    this.sbitmcls = "imageSelected"
  },
  mouseOut: function() {
    event.target.style.background = "#4a4b45";
  }
}
```

style:

```
.image {
  display: relative;
  background-color: #4a4b45;
  color: white;
  font-family: Rubik, "Bookman", Garamond, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-style: bold;
  line-height: 2em;
  height: 5%;
  border-left: 5px solid #4a4b45;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.imageSelected {
  display: relative;
  background-color: #575a51;
  color: white;
  font-family: Rubik, "Bookman", Garamond, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-style: bold;
  line-height: 2em;
  height: 5%;
  border-left: 5px solid blue;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

Is there a better way to implement this?

Thanks,

Comment: But your way is perfect @girish

Comment: why are you duplicating all the properties? Can't you set one global image class and then have 'selected' on it .image , and .image .selected ?

Answer (score 1):

You can almost completely do this in CSS with the [`:hover` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover).

```css
.image {
  /* your CSS for the image class */
}

.image.hovered, .image:hover {
  border-left-color: blue;
}

.image:hover {
  background-color: #575a51;
}
```

Your template just needs

```html
<ul class="image" @mouseover.once="$event.target.classList.add('hovered')">
```

This adds the `hovered` class to your element when it is first mouse-overed which keeps the blue border color while the background color returns to its default value.

```js
new Vue({el: '#app'})
```

```css
.image {
  display: relative;
  background-color: #4a4b45;
  color: white;
  font-family: Rubik, "Bookman", Garamond, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-style: bold;
  line-height: 2em;
  height: 5%;
  border-left: 5px solid #4a4b45;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.image.hovered, .image:hover {
  border-left-color: blue;
}

.image:hover {
  background-color: #575a51;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul class="image" @mouseover.once="$event.target.classList.add('hovered')">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/30" alt="" height="30" width="30">
    <span> Notification  </span>
  </ul>

  <ul class="image" @mouseover.once="$event.target.classList.add('hovered')">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/30" alt="" height="30" width="30">
    <span> Message  </span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why only once @mouseover.once?

Comment: @karthick seems OP wants to keep the blue border once the element is hovered, even after the mouse moves on. There's no point asking the `classList` to keep adding the same class every time the element is hovered so I used the `once` modifier

Answer (score 0):

Try binding class to data value, ex:

```
 <ul :class="{'imageSelected': selected === true, 'image': selected ===
 false}" @mouseover="mouseOver" @mouseleave="mouseOut"> ... data() {
 return {   selected: false   }; }, methods: {    mouseOver:
 function(name) {    this.selected = true; },
```